# Unity Tweak Tool hot corners resets after every restart?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, ubuntu-tweak

I've binded my top-right corner to show all windows and my bottom-center to show all workspaces. It works sweet.. But then I reboot and it's not binded anymore. If I go to the Ubuntu Tweak Tool, it's binded there(but not working), but if I reset and re-bind it, it's working.

How to fix this?

Comment: You can try solutions in this questions: [In 13.04 using Unity Tweak Tool hot corners stops working after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309301/in-13-04-using-unity-tweak-tool-hot-corners-stops-working-after-reboot) [“show desktop” with “hot corners” not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419205/show-desktop-with-hot-corners-not-working) [Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty doesn't utilize hot corners after rebooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450278/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-doesnt-utilize-hot-corners-after-rebooting)